# Xcode 6.1 - Map View appears blank in iOS7 simulator or iPhone 4

Tags: ios7, xcode6, ios7.1

Since I last updated to Xcode 6.1 and Yosemite, the map views in my app started to appear blank either in ios7.1 simulator or my iPhone4 (iOS7.1). 
I could replicate the situation by creating a brand new single view application with just a MKMapView and although it appears correctly in iOS8 simulators, in the iOS7.1 simulators or my iPhone4 it shows only a blank screen. The iOS Deployment Target is set to iOS 7.1.
I tested this simple app in a friend's Mac with Mavericks but the same situation occurs.
Is this some bug of Xcode 6.1 or SDK, or do I have to add something to run maps on iOS7?

Comment: I've installed Xcode 5.1 but then the app didn't run. I've put the ios7 SDK from Xcode 5.1 in my Xcode 6.1 and chose that SDK in my project but the app didn't run as well. I'm still stuck with a simple single view application with a blank map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same problem. To fix it, you have to disable Size Classes. Go to Storyboard and in the right sidebar, you should see a check box saying 'Use Size Classes' under 'Interface builder document'. Untick it and you should see the map again.

Read this to find out why this happens:

[iOS MkMapView blank after moving to Xcode 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26911716/ios-mkmapview-blank-after-moving-to-xcode-6)

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked! I was afraid I couldn't get my app working in iphones 4.